# Could Sha'ira romance affect my chances with Liara?

Tags: mass-effect

During Mass Effect 1, I can have a "romance" encounter with Sha'ira. If I choose to, will that affect my chances of romance with Liara?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, having the romantic encounter with Sha'ira does not affect your chances with Liara. The young archaeologist is very taken with her rescuer and only a direct rejection will hurt your chances at hitting it off with her.